# Variable is undefined every time I call a method

Tags: javascript

I'm building an ES5 weather app to get a better understanding of JavaScript. I've run into a problem, I've come up with a fix & got it working however I still don't understand why my original solution is giving me problems. I'm trying to understand JavaScript on a deeper level. TY.

**What I'm confused by:**

1. After I hit submit and make the API call, and everything is displayed on my screen, my second API call creates an additional paragraph HTML tag instead of replacing the initial one. This is because the following if statement is never true:

```
if (p1) {
      p1.innerHTML = `The tempature is currently: ${kelvinToFaren(weather.main.temp)}, with a high of ${kelvinToFaren(weather.main.temp_max)} and a low of ${kelvinToFaren(weather.main.temp_min)}`;
}
```

But I would think the second time around it would be true since I've already created it in the previous function. But it is always undefined. Why does this happen?

2. Also, I'd like to make a separate method called

   generateContent(p1)

Which would run:

```
p1.innerHTML += `The tempature is currently: ${kelvinToFaren(weather.main.temp)}, with a high of ${kelvinToFaren(weather.main.temp_max)} and a low of ${kelvinToFaren(weather.main.temp_min)}`;
```

But again p1 is always undefined.

**Wrap up:**
My solution was to add classes/Id's and search for them. If they are true then it's the second API call. And that works great. Yet I now feel like I'm missing something (in my understanding of JavaScript).

**My code:**

```
class UI {
  constructor() {  
    
  }
  showWeatherResults(weather) {
    let renderedSection;
    let p1;
    if (p1) {
      p1.innerHTML = `The tempature is currently: ${kelvinToFaren(weather.main.temp)}, with a high of ${kelvinToFaren(weather.main.temp_max)} and a low of ${kelvinToFaren(weather.main.temp_min)}`;
    } else {
      renderedSection = document.querySelector('#renderedContent');
      p1 = document.createElement("p");
      renderedSection.appendChild(p1);
      p1.innerHTML += `The tempature is currently: ${kelvinToFaren(weather.main.temp)}, with a high of ${kelvinToFaren(weather.main.temp_max)} and a low of ${kelvinToFaren(weather.main.temp_min)}`;
      this.clearInput();
    }
  }
  clearInput() {
    let input = document.querySelector('input');
    input.value = '';
  }
}
```

**Relevant HTML:**

```
<h1>Enter your zipcode here</h1>
<form>
  <input id="zipInput" type="text">
  <button id="zipButton">Submit</button>
</form>
<section id="renderedContent"></section>
```

**Index.js:**

```
const weatherApp = new WeatherApp;
const ui = new UI;
const zipButton = document.querySelector('#zipButton');

// Event listeners
zipButton.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const weatherResult = await weatherApp.getWeather()
  ui.showWeatherResults(weatherResult);
});
```

I have an additional JavaScript file called weather.js that handles the API call but it did not seem necessary to add.

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to everyone's help I have much cleaner code that works exactly how I wanted it and now I'm beginning to understand state & keyword this, better.

```
    class UI {
  constructor() {  
    this.renderedSection = document.querySelector('#renderedContent');
    this.p1 = document.createElement("p");
  }
  showWeatherResults(weather) {      
      const { renderedSection, p1, clearInput } = this;
      renderedSection.appendChild(p1);
      p1.innerHTML = `The tempature is currently: ${kelvinToFaren(weather.main.temp)}, with a high of ${kelvinToFaren(weather.main.temp_max)} and a low of ${kelvinToFaren(weather.main.temp_min)}`;
      clearInput();
  }
  clearInput() {
    let input = document.querySelector('input');
    input.value = '';
  }
}
```

Comment: ES5? You have A LOT of ES6+ features here.

Comment: Sorry I meant ES6, thank you!

Comment: Also, the problem is completely unrelated to what version of JS the code is running. Your logic is faulty - you *always* start with `p1` as `undefined` when the method is called. Even if you reassign it, the next time it's called you create an entirely separate variable. You don't retain the state from the previous execution.

Comment: `let p1; if (p1)`  well, that's ALWAYS going to be false.  I think you're trying to keep `p1` around between calls.  in that case, try replacing `p1` with `this.p1` and make it a member of the class (property of the object - or whatever the right terminology is).

Answer (score 1):

Variables, declared inside a function, don't hold their values between invocations of a function.

`let p1;` declares the variable. It doesn't assign it a value. It will always be `undefined` until you give it one in the `else` block.

You need to either:

- Search the DOM for the node when you create the variable
- Declare the variable outside of the function

Comment: Thank you! I tried declaring it in the constructor but that didn't work. Do I have to declare it in the global scope?

Comment: It has to be declared in a scope you can access it from. You could make it a property of the object instance instead of a variable.

Comment: @BBaccs you probably want it as an instance property. It's part of the state of the object.

Comment: I think you just need to say `this.p1` instead of just `p1`.

Comment: That's very useful. I'll need to learn about the state object and instance properties. Ty!

Comment: @BBaccs there is no "state object". The "state" is just a general term for "data this depends on". You *object* depends on the value of `p1`. It's part of its state. Hence it makes sense to make it part of the object.

Comment: Ahh okay, gotcha. I read that wrong, thank you for clarifying.